# jquery delegate with anchors in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a site that is working perfectly in firefox and chrome, but in IE 8 (haven't tried 7 yet) some of the .on delegates aren't working.  Specifically the ones used on anchor tags.

HTML:

```
    <ui id='daylist'>
      <li><a href="#" class="day-selected"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>2</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>3</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>4</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>5</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>6</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>7</span></a></li>
    </ui>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('#daylist').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        alert('clicked');
        pickDay(this); //this isn't important, the alert isn't even happening
        return false;
    });
```

I have jquery 1.7 included.  My problem is that the alert just doesn't get called at all.  But only in IE

Comment: IE 9 works well. This problem occurs only in IE8 and bellow.

Comment: do you know what the problem is?  and how to fix it?

Comment: grr, found the answer - the ui is supposed to be ul.  IE is the only one that cares.  What an annoying waste of an hour

Comment: At this times you have to get a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML:

```
<ul id='daylist'>
  <li><a href="#" class="day-selected"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>1</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>2</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>3</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>4</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>5</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>6</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Day </span><span class='number'>7</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Internet Explorer up to version 8 doesn't accept unknown HTML tags (such as HTML5 tags). You can solve this however (if need) by using some Javascript like HTML5shim or HTML5shiv.

Comment: hmm, nope doesn't help.  What's frustrating is that I also have some others where i do click, div and those ones work perfectly.  It's just this set of anchors that's getting me.

Comment: Haha, the HTML element is called `ui` instead of `ul`. Time to go to bed :-)

Comment: i'm marking this a the answer because it was a good point that i just didn't do (copying and pasting from the other parts that i wanted to make delegates, this one it didn't matter)